# Can we burn the zombie-whales tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

While conducting a review of the suggested edits queue, I noticed a user had made a change to the wiki for [zombie-whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie-whales). This piqued my interest, as I had never seen this tag before, so I dug into the tag's existence.

There is only one question tagged [zombie-whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie-whales), specifically, [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/71935/6986), and it makes absolutely no sense in the context of the question. Looking at the edit history, the tag was added by a user other than the questioner in what appears to be either an attempt to further the joke intended by the question or a defacement of the question. (In either case, that edit shouldn't have been made, in my opinion.)

[zombie-whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie-whales) can also quite clearly be covered by a combination of [animals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [zombies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies) (or just the latter, as the tag info indicates it can be used for any undead creature).

Can we burn the zombie-whales tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By all means.  I created that tag and edited it to participate in Pavel's humorous question.

I have no idea why someone approved that edit.

Comment: If you have at least 2,000 reputation, any edits you make to questions or answers don't need to be approved by the community. See the [privileges](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page in the help center.

Comment: When I edited it, the system told me that it would wait to be peer-reviewed.  I'm pretty sure I saw that.

Comment: Yes, I'm told "You do not yet have [tag wiki edit privileges](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).  Your edit must be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed".  So I guess someone with 20K+ accepted it.

Comment: @Frostfyre Actually it is [5k](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to approve tag wiki edits. Editing the tag wiki without approval is [20k](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). So pete's edit had to be approved by another 5k user. Pedantry!

Comment: In any case, the tag can be killed, killed with fire.

Comment: @kingledion My comment was in response to Pete's answer mentioning the question that was edited, not the tag edit.

Comment: @Frostfyre So confusing!

Comment: I think it should be pretty obvious that I know I can edit questions by now. I had to edit Pavel's question to put the tag on there, after all....

Answer (score 6):

For sure.  It’s a clear case of an overly specific tag even if it did make sense.